# Is this trace normal?

Tags: traceroute

I was trying to access Paypal dev blog but got a connection timed out error instead. Other sites are working fine. So I did a trace route if I would see something flaky. Indeed something came up.

[image]

Would anyone able to tell me what I am looking at here? Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a loop within [TMNet](https://wq.apnic.net/whois-search/static/search.html?query=219.93.218.177) network (Malaysia).

Different traceroute from Europe to the Paypal Dev Blog IP are perfectly normal and reach the intended destination.

A [traceroute made from Singapour](http://ops.pacific.net.sg/tools/traceroute.php?host=173.0.94.50&submit=Traceroute!) is also normal :

> Traceroute from Pacnet Singapore to 173.0.94.50
>
> HOST: kirchhoff.pacific.net.sg    Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst
>   StDev
>     1.|-- vl8.scipk006.pacific.net.  0.0%    10    0.3   4.4   0.2  36.2  11.3
>     2.|-- te0-1-0-1.gw3.sjc1.10026.  0.0%    10  172.3 172.4 172.3 172.6   0.1
>     3.|-- sjo-b21-link.telia.net     0.0%    10  177.8 178.0 177.6 179.1   0.5
>     4.|-- paypal-ic-310953-sjo-b21.  0.0%    10  172.8 172.8 172.6 172.9   0.1
>     5.|-- 64.4.244.158               0.0%    10  177.4 177.5 177.4 178.0   0.2
>     6.|-- 64.4.244.104               0.0%    10  179.7 181.9 179.6 192.1   3.7
>     7.|-- 64.4.244.43                0.0%    10  202.3 202.3 202.2 202.5   0.1
>     8.|-- 64.4.244.196               0.0%    10  198.4 198.1 198.0 198.4   0.1
>     9.|-- ???                       100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
>    10.|-- devblog.paypal.com        10.0%    10  200.6 200.6 200.4 200.8   0.1

Comment: I was trying to access that site in office earlier and it was unreachable - connection timed out. I am at home now and I can access Paypal dev blog fine. The weird thing is, actually the loop you observed not only happens when I do a trace to Paypal - it happens to every other sites basically that is not hosted in Malaysia. But, surfing the web is fine and no problem at all - only that I find it difficult to troubleshoot sometimes. @JFL does this seems like configuration problem at their end that I can validly shout at my service provider?

Comment: this may indicate different things, maybe a proxy.. no way to determine what. (and network outside your control are off topic here)